# How to get character count limitation including default name-Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, character-limit

I am trying to get character limit for input box ,but the input field has default value.

if character limit exceeds text has to appear at 0 limit(Not popup)

if i use below code it is not working fine for my requirement(say default value already exist).

can I know how to include default value and set message if it come to 0

```
class Company extends React.Component {
state = {
      Title: this.props.selectedTable.Title,
      chars_left: 50,
      max_char:50
    }

   handleCharacterCount= (event) => {
    const charCount = event.target.value.length;
    const maxChar = this.state.max_char;
    const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
    this.setState({ chars_left: charLength });
    //this.setState({sTitle: e.target.value});
   }
   render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <textArea
        type="text"
        maxLength="50"
        required
        onChange={this.handleCharacterCount}
        value={this.state.Title}/>
      />
      <p>{this.state.chars_left}</p>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to set the message if it comes to 0?

Comment: down to input box

Comment: `onChange` will only fire when you click off of the textarea. If you want immediate updates use `onInput`.

Comment: you mean the code is write instead of on change use onInput

Comment: No, just offering an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
state = {
  Title: this.props.selectedTable.Title,
  chars_left: 50 - this.props.selectedTable.Title.length,
  max_char:50
}



handleCharacterCount= (event) => {
const charCount = event.target.value.length;
const maxChar = this.state.max_char;
const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
this.setState({ chars_left: charLength,Title: event.target.value })}



render() {
return (
 <div>
  <textArea
    type="text"
    maxLength="50"
    required
    onChange={this.handleCharacterCount}
    value={this.state.Title}/>
  />
  {
    !this.state.chars_left &&
      <p>text has to appear at 0 limit</p>
  }
  <p>{this.state.chars_left}</p>
</div>)}
```

Comment: sure let me check

Comment: but i need to check the default value characters also

Comment: don't get it. please explain. Do you want to count default value characters also?

Comment: I mean , i have default values which appears in the text box, will this also be counted

Comment: if there is 50 max character, i have default name already exist-----if default name is 'XYZ' there my count should be 47

Comment: in the state add it.
chars_left: 50 - this.props.selectedTable.Title.length

Comment: commented the line in my question... is that ok

Comment: chars_left: 50 - this.props.selectedTable.Title.length......... this should be worked. Do you want that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now you can see the code what you want actually

Comment: i need to set message based on api response,it should say 'data saved successfully' only if its 200 status, can i get some suggestions

Comment: Where do you want to set that message? Can you try it:  if(response.status===200) { this.setState({message:'Data saved successfully'})}

Comment: Should i set in action page itself??

Comment: at component level how do we get to know response status??

Comment: When you get your api response, then you can set a state object according to the response.status. If the state object is true then you can show the message or hide. Let me know if you get it or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172813/discussion-between-jmr-and-md-isfar-uddin-alnur).

Comment: Should i maintain any redux state or from network tab.

Comment: isfar Uddin AINur  can you please  look into this issue 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50776961/how-to-remove-board-from-redux-store-react-js-redux