# How to Remove Board from Redux store-React js, redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here i am creating new board by clicking on button, Once i enter board page i have option of creating new widgets

If user is not creating new widget and click backtoboards button , boards should not be created

here board is getting created,i am able to see the boards with out saving,

If i refresh the page board is not seen.

can i get some suggestion on how to prevent creating board if back to board button is clicked

click on back to board below function will be called

Back to board

```
manageShowBoard = (selectedBoard) => {
this.setState({ selectedBoard });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to pass the `selectedStoryboard` as the payload of the action, then simply:

```
case types.REMOVE_STORYBOARD:
{
  const boardToRemove = ... // get from action payload
  return {
     ...state,
    boardList: state.boardList.filter(board => board !== boardToRemove);
  };
}
```

Comment: onclick of back to boards??

Comment: @JMR I am telling you how. You have to decide when. That's your app logic.

Comment: Ok Thanks  for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach can be in your new Board component (where you are creating widgets), you can keep the widgets count. When the user clicks the back button, you can check the widgets count.
If your widgets count is greater than 0, then you can add that board in the Parent component where you can maintain all boards data.

Parent:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.boardsList = [];
  }

  updateBoards = (newBoard) => {
    this.boardsList.push(newBoard);
    this.setState({renderAgain: true});
  }

  render(){
    return <Board updateBoards={this.updateBoards} />;
  }

}
```

Board:

```
class Board {

  onClickBackButton = () => {
    if(widgetsCount > 0){
      this.props.updateBoards(boardData);
    }
    else {
      ...normal back button functionality...
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: if(!currentWidgetList || !currentWidgetList.length)   but still if  i click back i am able to see the boards

Comment: Then I think your display function is not correct. It should be a map function of boardsList array and according to the above code, the boardsList will only update when the widgetsList of a new board will be greater than zero. So no new boards with zero widgets will appear.

Comment: When i click on the create button board is created, there if i just come back need to remove the board from redux store, irrespective of widget

Comment: if the length of widget is 0 then redux store will be having my board already